# Domain and range of $f(x)=\arcsin[e^{-x}]+ \arcsin [e^x]$

Tags: functions

What is the domain and range of 
$f(x)=\arcsin[e^{-x}]+ \arcsin [e^x]$ where $[x]$ denotes greatest integer function?

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what is your definition of "range"? (I'm guessing it does not mean "codomain", am I right?)

Comment: I cleaned up the MathJax syntax in your post. Can you add what you have already tried to solve the problem? In particular, what does the domain of $\arcsin$ imply for $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$?

Comment: wythagoras sir I didn't get you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To find domain**

$-1\leq [e^x]\leq 1$

$0<e^x<2$ (since $e^x>0$)

$-\infty<x<\ln 2$

Similarly,$-1\leq [e^{-x}]\leq 1$

$0<e^{-x}<2$ (since $e^x>0$)

$-\infty<-x<\ln 2$

$-\ln 2<x<\infty$

therefore, the required domain is $x\in\left(-\ln 2,\ln 2\right)$

**To find range**

Since,$-\ln 2<x<\ln 2$

$\frac{1}{2}<e^x<2$

$[e^x]=0,1$

$\arcsin [e^x]=0,\frac{\pi}{2}$

Simlarly,$-\ln 2<-x<\ln 2$

$\frac{1}{2}<e^{-x}<2$

$[e^{-x}]=0,1$

$\arcsin [e^{-x}]=\frac{\pi}{2},0$

Thus $f(x)=0+\frac{\pi}{2}$ or $f(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}+0$
$f(0)=arcsin(1)+arcsin(1)=\pi$

Thus Range=$\frac{\pi}{2},\pi$

Comment: You forgot $f(0)=\pi$

Comment: Yes. I indeed forgot. I have edited.

Answer (score 2):

We need $-1\le e^x<2$ and  $-1\le e^{-x}<2$

But for real $x,e^x>0$

Now $e^x<2\iff x<\ln2$

and $e^{-x}<2\iff e^x>2^{-1}\iff x>-\ln2$

Comment: I didn't get you

Comment: @saisaandeep, If $\arcsin x=y, x=\sin y$ and for real $y,-1\le\sin y\le1$

Comment: This is not correct. **You forgot the floor function.** IMO, the domain should be $x \in (-\ln 2, \ln 2)$ and $f(x) \in \{\pi, \pi/2\}$

Comment: @gammatester, Sorry could not discern the floor function. Thanks

Comment: What is floor function